# Detect the date format C#

Tags: c#, validation, date

I have some automated C# windows services to upload text to the database. The 'text' is generated by a third party application where we don't have any control.

My issue is that the text contains a column for date. 
The default date format is DD/MM/YY. But some times we get MM/YY/DD

Is there any tricky way to identify or convert MM/YY/DD to DD/MM/YY. The data might only contain date for three, four days. So I plan to check if the date is in tolerance with three or four days, it will be accepted. Other wise manually correct it.
**For example,**

`14/08/17 is accepted`

`08/17/14 is not accepted. Logic should convert this to 14/08/17`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Too vague, show an example and the issue you had. You have an idea, show the code that uses that idea, then tell us where you're stuck or why that approach doesn't work.

Comment: What you're asking isn't really possible. What if the date entered is ambiguous, like `01/02/2017`? Is that the right way round and it's 1st Feb or wrong way round and it's 2nd Jan?

Comment: This is doomed to failure, I'm afraid. If you get 01/02/17 then it could be February 1st or January 2nd. Unless you can *guarantee* to get a value which has a day-of-month of 13 or more, you're not going to be able to do this reliably.

Comment: @JonSkeet Haha we used the same date :)

Comment: Your second example also might be 17th Aug 2014, you can't say this is not accepted by any logic

Comment: The only way to be sure is to expect an unambiguous format (like `yyyy/mm/dd`) or specify the month in text rather than numeric format (`14/aug/2017`) but that leads to language problems.

Comment: Are these two the only formats possible, or can you also get MM/DD/YY?

Comment: @Vanna Er what? That just adds even more ambiguity!

Comment: (To all the above comments ), I can ensure that the date will not go earlier than 3 days.

Comment: @Rauf: How many accepted dates you have like `14/08/17`? Are they in the same month, year or even close to each other?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It will be close to each other. For example, if I receive data on 14/08/2017, all the date filed might be for 12, 13 or 14.

Comment: The question can now be reformulated as "will the restriction of max 3 days from current date always be enough to resolve ambiguity between the two allowed formats, for all dates"? 
It's not obvious that this is the case, but I think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and parse with the good format, if it goes ok there is no problem, it will return the date. If it goes wrong, you tryparse with the 'secondary format'. If everything goes ok, it will return the date.

Note that if the parsed date it's more than 3 days ahead, it won't count as a valid date and will return null.

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue)
{
     int daysBetween = (dateValue-DateTime.Now).Days
     if(daysBetween < 4)
     {
          return dateValue
     }
}
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MM/yy/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue)
{
     int daysBetween = (dateValue-DateTime.Now).Days
     if(daysBetween < 4)
     {
          return dateValue;
     }
}
return null
```

If null gets returned, you'll have an invalid date, if not, that will be the parsed date

Comment: @Dle Just for info. The third party application is VB 6 application. If I check how the default date format taken by VB6, will it give some lights ?

Comment: If that app returns those formatted dates and you don't have any control over it, i don't think it will help you